# Spring's Autowired and InitializingBean

Tags: spring, autowired

I currently employ the following "pattern" on all my Spring component/configuration/service classes:

```
@Component
final class SomeComponent implements InitializingBean {
  private SomeBean someBean;

  @Autowired
  public SomeComponent(SomeBean someBean) {
    this.someBean = someBean;
  }

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    Assert.state(someBean != null, "SomeBean should not be null.");
  }

  public void someMethod() {
    someBean.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Should I really be implementing things like this or if I am just adding up to initialization time by making pointless assertions? Does Spring make any guarantees about the nullity of injected beans?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says:

> By default, the autowiring fails whenever zero candidate beans are available; the default behavior is to treat annotated methods, constructors, and fields as indicating required dependencies.

So yes, you're making pointless assertions. BTW, you could do these assertions in the constructor directly, or at least in a @PostConstruct-annotated method, instead of having to override InitializingBean.